# Delete strings: {name, John, John Doe, Doe} to {name, John Doe}

Tags: string-manipulation

I am not very familiar with coding and I am trying to solve the following:

Input:

```
{name, John, John Doe, Doe}
```

Output:

```
{name, John Doe}
```

So, it should delete {John, Doe} only if there is a string which contains already both of them.

I would be very grateful for any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to the forum! You should watch the [TOUR](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
strings = {"name", "John", "John Doe", "Doe"};

Pick[strings,
 BitAnd @@ (IdentityMatrix[Length[strings]] +
    Boole[Outer[StringFreeQ, strings, strings]]), 1]
```

> {"name", "John Doe"}

Or equivalently:

```
Pick[strings,
 MapIndexed[StringFreeQ[Delete[strings, #2], #] &, strings],
 ConstantArray[True, Length[strings] - 1]]
```

The code below matches only whole words:

```
strings = {"to", "tomorrow", "name", "John", "John Doe", "Doe"}

Pick[strings,
 And @@@ MapIndexed[StringFreeQ[Delete[strings, #2],
     " " | StartOfString ~~ # ~~ EndOfString | " "] &, strings]]
```

> {"to", "tomorrow", "name", "John Doe"}

Comment: Great! thank you very much for your help, Coolwater!

Comment: Is it possible to include a condition that allows the following:

Input:
{"to", "tomorrow", "name", "John", "John Doe", "Doe"}

Output:
{"to", "tomorrow", "name",  "John Doe"}

So, {"to"} should not be deleted. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Coffee_09 I've updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that the list will contain strings, not variables:

```
L = {"name", "John", "John Doe", "Doe"};
```

Delete element sequences like `{"John", "Doe"}` that are together contained in a single string `"John Doe"`:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, Orderless];
(f[Sequence @@ #, x___] = f[x]) & /@ Select[StringSplit /@ L, Length[#] > 1 &];
f[x___] = {x};
f @@ L
```

> {"John Doe", "name"}

This method does not keep the original sorting order of the list. If this order needs to be kept, we can replace the last line with

```
SortBy[f @@ L, Position[L, #][[1, 1]] &]
```

> {"name", "John Doe"}

## update

In order to deal with multiple mentions of "John", for example, a slight modification to the `Orderless` pattern using [`Repeated ..`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html):

```
L = {"name", "John", "John", "John Doe", "Doe"};
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, Orderless];
(f[Sequence @@ Thread[# ..], x___] = f[x]) & /@
  Select[StringSplit /@ L, Length[#] > 1 &];
f[x___] = {x};
SortBy[f @@ L, Position[L, #][[1, 1]] &]
```

> {"name", "John Doe"}

Comment: Thank you very much, Roman! Is there a possibility to keep the original sorting order?

Comment: To be honest this is probably not the most efficient solution, but I wrote it down as an exercise in using pattern-matching on `Orderless` functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, Roman!

Answer (score 2):

```
# /. Flatten[Cases[#, 
      x_ /; StringContainsQ[x, " "] :> 
       Thread[StringSplit[x] -> Nothing]]] &[{"name", "John", 
  "John Doe", "Doe"}]
```

> {"name", "John Doe"}